# How to create Dynamic SQL in Pentaho Report Designer?

Tags: sql, dynamic, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I have a requirement where columns of the SQL will be generated based some selection, these columns are coming from `Metric` dimension but there is no metric ID present in Fact table.
SQL would be something like below:

```
SELECT Location_Nbr, Day_Nbr, (Column_List- Coming from some other query)
FROM (Table_Name - Coming from same query which is providing Columns to be selected)
```

I tried creating the SQL query but I get an error saying there is not a business relation between these tables. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Dynamic SQL in Pentaho Report Designer, you need to use

`custom jdbc connection` in data source

then in master report `query name`, select `message format`

type your dynamic query in `message Pattern`

```
select   
$(dynamic_data) as 'data' from table_name;
```